# wtf-form Email validation doesn't pass when email is optional

Tags: flask-wtforms, wtforms

I can't see what I'm doing wrong in a FlaskForm. I'd like the email address to be optional.

Even if an entered email  is valid, it does not pass validation if email is optional.
It might be my imagination but I think this used to work fine. I did update all my requirements recently, did something change? I'm now using:

```
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
WTForms==2.2.1
```

example:

```
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Optional,  Email

class ProfileForm2(FlaskForm):
    """
    Form for user to add or edit profile. Email optional
    """
    # this passes with valid email:
    email_req =StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()]) 
    # this never passes with same valid email
    email = StringField('Email (optional)', validators=[Optional(), Email()])
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

My bad. There was a bug in my view function for the form.
Not good for my very first Stackoverflow question. Sorry.